# Which approach should I take for design of tables in my back-end system?

Tags: database

Use Case for my application:

- There are 8 semesters in a law faculty at a university
- There are three chances for a student to pass an exam if she/he fails
- There are average 8 subjects in each semester

For the design of database tables in the back-end system there are two options which come into my mind:

i) I should create one table for each semester there which has 8 columns in average with the three changes there will be duplicate ids in it, if a student fails then he/she need to give the second chance exam.

ii) I should create three tables with 8 semester in it that each going to have around 8 subjects, and this is going to be a long table with 64 columns.

Which option should I take or do you have any other option to suggest?

Comment: Please limit your post to one question in particular: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have suggested a rewording of your post for clarity. Your question may be still too generic though. The question on how a data model should be designed into database tables largely depends on the functionality you'll need to access the data as part of your application. Did you define the detailed use cases, yet? Do you have an idea on how many entities (e.g. student records) you have to handle?

Answer (score 0):

The 4 main entities you've mentioned are:

1. Semester
2. Students
3. Subjects
4. Exams

So as a starter:

1. A table called SEMESTERS, primary key SEM_ID, cols START/END dates, NAME
2. A table called STUDENTS, primary key STU_ID, cols NAME
3. A table called SUBJECTS, primary key SUB_ID, cols NAME, PASS_MARK, MAX_FAILS
4. You need a intersection table showing which students attend which classes, so, a table called STUDENT_SUBJECTS, primary STS_ID.
5. Now, you could have a EXAMS table that is a child of SUBJECTS, then have a table called STUDENT_EXAMS which is a child of EXAMS and STUDENT_SUBJECTS in which you record exam results. Or keep it simple, don't have this EXAMS and STUDENT_EXAMS table, and instead add cols EXAM_RESULT1, EXAM_RESULT2, EXAM_RESULT3 on STUDENT_SUBJECTS to record exam results.